# Blockhound is not detecting straightforward blocking code

Tags: spring-webflux, blockhound

Using spring boot webflux, I'm trying Blockhound for a very simple blocking call, but it doesn't seem to be detecting it.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>blockhound</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

in main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BlockHound.install();
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
  }
```

My blocking endpoint:

```
    @GetMapping("/block")
    public Mono<String> block() {
        String a = Mono.just("block").block();
        return Mono.just(a);
    }
```

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

When I use UUID.randomUUID() in my endpoint, I get the error related to a blocking FileInputStream#readBytes used by randomUUID().
So I suppose My install is good

Comment: It’s because you are install it wrong, Does this answer your question? [How to add BlockHound to a spring boot app to detect blocking calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58013744/how-to-add-blockhound-to-a-spring-boot-app-to-detect-blocking-calls)

Comment: I see nothing wrong with my install. By the way, I'm seeing an error when I use UUID.randomUUID(); which uses FileInputStream#readBytes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing is wrong here, you've just hit a corner case.

`Mono.just()` is a rather *special* kind of `Mono` in more ways than one (which is why I despair at its use in so many simple "getting started" style examples, but I digress) - since you're literally just wrapping a value inside a dummy publisher, it *never* needs to block in order to return its value, even if you call the block method. The method name might imply you're blocking, but [you can trivially verify from the source code that it just returns a value](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/main/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/MonoJust.java). There's therefore no blocking operation occurring, and so nothing for Blockhound to complain about.

If you were to add another operator in the mix, even if it has no real-world effect:

`String a = Mono.just("block").cache().block();`

...then you'll see Blockhound start complaining, as you're no longer directly using the special case of `MonoJust`.

Blockhound is doing exactly what it should here, the issue is that you're (very understandably) *expecting* something to block which doesn't.